# best way to clear contents of .NET's StringBuilder

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, .net-3.5

I would like to ask what you think is the best way (lasts less / consumes less resources) to clear the contents in order to reuse a StringBuilder. Imagine the following scenario:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var whatever in whateverlist)
{
  sb.Append("{0}", whatever);
}

//Perform some stuff with sb

//Clear stringbuilder here

//Populate stringbuilder again to perform more actions
foreach(var whatever2 in whateverlist2)
{
  sb.Append("{0}", whatever2);
}
```

And when clearing StringBuilder I can think of two possibilities:

```
sb = new StringBuilder();
```

or

```
sb.Length = 0;
```

What is the best way to clear it and why?

Thank you.

EDIT: I ment with current .NET 3.5 version.

Comment: Not an answer, but interesting to read: http://bobondevelopment.com/2007/06/11/three-ways-to-clear-a-stringbuilder/

Comment: What's the reason for not including the StringBuilder.Clear() method as an alternative?

Comment: @Rune: c# 4.0 ain't out yet, it's only in 4.0. On MSDN it says: Supported in: 4.

Comment: lucky for me that c#4.0 is out http://blogs.msdn.com/somasegar/default.aspx

Comment: I wonder why `Length` is writable, but there isn't a read/write "Text" property?  Saying `sb.Text = "";` would seem clearer that `sb.Length = 0;`, and a `Text` property would also help in the common scenario where one would otherwise have to say `sb.Length = 0; sb.Append(StuffToStartWith);`.

Comment: @supercat Probably because a `.Text` property encourages people to accidentially write `sb.Text = sb.Text + nextString;`, defeating the whole point of using a `StringBuilder` in the first place.

Comment: @LWChris: It would be reasonable to require that code wanting to set the content use a `Set` method rather than a property, but if one took such an approach I see no reason `Length` shouldn't be treated suitably, especially since there would be uses for different ways of handling lengthening and shortening scenarios.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you're doing this in .NET 2.0 or 3.5, write an extension method to do it like this:

```
/// <summary>
///     Clears the contents of the string builder.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value">
///     The <see cref="StringBuilder"/> to clear.
/// </param>
public static void Clear(this StringBuilder value)
{
    value.Length = 0;
    value.Capacity = 0;
}
```

Then, you can clear it like this:

```
someStringBuilder.Clear();
```

Then, when 4.0 comes out, you can ditch your extension method in favor of the 4.0 version.

**UPDATE**: It's probably not a good idea to set Capacity to zero. That will guarantee reallocations when you append to the builder, if you're reusing the same instance. However, the memory in the instance of the builder is not released until you set the Capacity to a very small value (such as 1). The default value of the Capacity property is 16. You might want to consider using 16, or (though it's less efficient) setting the capacity twice:

- Set it to 1 or zero to clear the memory
- Set it to your original Capacity value (which may differ from 16) to restore it.

Comment: Neat Method. Just what I was looking for.

Comment: I would recommend against clearing the capacity, except when the `StringBuilder` is known to have held something *unusually* big.  Especially in earlier versions of .net, if one will be repeatedly building strings of more than 42,500 characters, clearing the buffer after each string will cause extra objects to be allocated in the Large Object Heap every time the buffer has to re-grow.  That's a Bad Thing.

Comment: Setting the capacity to 0 is an interesting idea. When just using Clear or just setting the length to 0, a memory leak can occur when Insert() is used repeatedly, because the Capacity keeps growing despite the Clear. (see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574469/memory-leak-in-stringbuilder-when-using-insert-and-clear

Answer (score 32):

In .NET 4.0 you can call `sb.Clear()` but in older versions you should set `sb.Length = 0`.

The `Clear()` method was added in .NET 4.0.

Comment: If you're reusing it wouldn't you want to reuse the buffer?

Comment: depends on the variance of how much big the string created the first time compared to the string created the second time.. Or at least I would think so

Answer (score 16):

Create the new StringBuilder.  The old one maintains resources associated with it (buffer of maximum length, for example) that are best just garbage collected away.

Answer (score 12):

From Community Content on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx):

> To effectively clear your
>   stringbuilder without destroying it
>   use:
>
> ```
>  someStringBuilder.length = 0;
>  someStringBuilder.capacity = 0;
> ```
>
> This destroys both its contents and
>   resizes it to zero. As noted above
>   clear the size can impact smaller
>   applications.

Answer (score 10):

I think you are doing premature optimization.

I would bet that doing `sb.Length=0;` would be the fastest to keep from creating another object and placing another object aside for GC to eventually collect.

I think creating a new StringBuilder would be the best shot for memory concerns. and setting `sb.Length` would be the best shot for speed concerns..

Answer (score 5):

In  .NET Framework 4 new methods were introduced in `StringBuilder` class. Method name is "Clear". This method helps you to clear or remove values or data from `StringBuilder` objects.

Here is example for this.

```
    System.Text.StringBuilder objSB = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    //Append values
    objSB.Append("This is .Net Blog.");
    objSB.Append("You can get latest C# Tips over here.");

    //Display on screen
    Response.Write(objSB.ToString());
    Response.Write("<br/><br/>");

    //Clear object using Clear method
    objSB.Clear();

    //Append another values
    objSB.Append("This blog is very useful for .Net Beginners");

    Response.Write("After Clear<br/><br/>");
    //Display on screen
    Response.Write(objSB.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to reduce memory usage I would use the CLR Profiler to check how much memory your StringBuilder objects are using through their lifecycle using the methods others have described above. Then you can satisfy yourself that the option you choose is suitable for your needs and is releasing the resources you need it to.

Answer (score 2):

[C# In A Nutshell](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/) To clear the contents of a `StringBuilder`, there are two ways:

1. Set its `Length` to zero:

   > Setting a StringBuilder’s `Length` to `zero` doesn’t shrink its internal capacity. So, if the StringBuilder previously contained one million characters, it will continue to occupy around 2 MB of memory after zeroing its Length.
2. Instantiate a new one:

   > If you want to `release the memory`, you must create a new StringBuilder and allow the old one to drop out of scope (and be garbage collected), with this approach you can solve the previous item problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the best way to clear it is to use `sb = new StringBuilder();`.  That being said, I think it'd be even better if you made a new string builder object altogether.

**EDIT**

I hope it goes without saying that this is the best solution.

```
public StringBuilder MakeString(IEnumerable<CoolType> list)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach(var whatever in list)
    {
        sb.Append("{0}", whatever);
    }
}

var sb = MakeString(whateverList);
// Do stuff
// Clear stuff
sb = MakeString(whateverList2);
```

Comment: sb = new StringBuilder() IS making a new string builder object.

Comment: Doing that DOES make a new string builder object altogether.

Comment: I think Matt means declare a new variable FOR the new `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Sorry, to clairify I'm recommending doing something like this: var wellNamedStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

Answer (score 0):

Just call Clear() method just set length = 0 ,
We can set Capacity = 0 also, if we want to save memory

```
public StringBuilder Clear() {
        this.Length = 0;
        return this;
 }
```

Ref: In [referencesource.microsoft.com](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,adf60ee46ebd299f)

Answer (score 0):

```
// P.S. to be ultra efficient 
// make a good guess at the initial allocation too !!!!
int PerWhatever_SizeEstimate = 4; // a guess of average length... you known your data
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( whateverlist.Length * PerWhatever_SizeEstimate);

// reallocation needed? 
// if you want to be efficient speed and memory wise... 
sb.Length = 0;  // rest internal index but don't release/resize memory
// if a ...BIG... difference in size
if( whatever2.Length < whatever.Length * 2/3  
 || whatever2.Length > whatever.Length * 1.5)
{
    //scale capacity appropriately
    sb.Capaciy = sb.Capacity * whatever2.Length / whatever.Length;
}
```